# How to reorder the matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Does anyone could tell me how to reorder the matrix:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

To:

```
[[15, 10, 5],
 [14, 9, 4],
 [13, 8, 3],
 [12, 7, 2],
 [11, 6, 1]]
```

Comment: For a numpy array this needs a `transpose` and one or more axis `reverse`.  There are `flip` and `rot90` functions that some or all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question `numpy`, I surmise that those are numpy matrix, and you are looking for a numpy solution (otherwise, if those are lists, Ann's zip is the correct solution).

For numpy you can

```py
M[::-1,::-1].T
```

Example

```py
M=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
M[::-1,::-1].T
```

returns

```
array([[15, 10,  5],
       [14,  9,  4],
       [13,  8,  3],
       [12,  7,  2],
       [11,  6,  1]])
```

as expected

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using numpy, like so:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

transformed_matrix = matrix[::-1].T[::-1]


# array([[15, 10,  5],
#        [14,  9,  4],
#        [13,  8,  3],
#        [12,  7,  2],
#        [11,  6,  1]])
```

`matrix[::-1]` gives you the original matrix in reverse order (i.e. `[11, 12, 13...]` first and `[1, 2, 3...]` last).

Taking the transpose of that with `.T` rotates the matrix about - swapping rows and columns.

Lastly, indexing the transpose with [::-1] reverses the order, putting `[15, 14, 13...]` first and `[5, 4, 3...]` last.

Comment: I can't understand why, but `M[::-1].T[::-1]` is slightly slower than `M[::-1,::-1].T` (order of 600 vs 700 μs. Not much difference. But big enough to be sure it is not just random)

Comment: That's really interesting! Thanks for taking the time to comparing the two like that - given me something to think about!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `zip()` method to transpose your matrix:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

print([list(i)[::-1] for i in zip(*m)][::-1])
```

Output:

```
[[15, 10, 5],
 [14, 9, 4],
 [13, 8, 3],
 [12, 7, 2],
 [11, 6, 1]]
```

The index `[::-1]` reverses the array.